# Test accessibility with webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver, uiaccessibility

I have web application and I need to make sure that all controls are reachable from keyboard.
The easiest way is to TAB through all of them but it's not very reliable because sometimes we need to use arrow up/down and also TAB can change state of control.

Does anybody have experience in web driver for accessibility testing?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got proper solution for the Accessibility testing? As I am comprehending your post at  http://www.diwebsity.com/2016/11/10/selenium-accessibility-testing/. http://www.diwebsity.com/2016/11/10/selenium-accessibility-testing/. I am facing below issue can you please guide me in this? 

"OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='extension-commands-config']"}
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)

Answer (score 1):

There is a JAVA [accessibility lib](https://github.com/nikulkarni/webdriver-accessibility) for the WebDriver. It helps you run accessibility audits.

Comment: Thank you. This tool is based on Chrome Accessibility Developer tool which does not check that all elements can be reachable from keyboard.

Comment: Have you try it in combination [with WAVE](http://watirmelon.com/2013/02/12/automated-local-accessibility-testing-using-wave-and-webdriver/) tool?

Comment: I did. WAVE gives you a lot of errors that don't make a lot of sense. If you try it with google.com you will see that WAVE highlights problems which are actually not a problems.

Comment: @ekostadinov Have you got proper solution for the Accessibility testing? As I am comprehending your post at  http://www.diwebsity.com/2016/11/10/selenium-accessibility-testing/. http://www.diwebsity.com/2016/11/10/selenium-accessibility-testing/. I am facing below issue can you please guide me in this? 

"OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException
Message=no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='extension-commands-config']"}
(Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106).

Seeking for the help.

Comment: @Developer this looks like `WebDriver` error, not related to `WAVE Evaluator`. Maybe you can you try with some other element and then hit the keyboard shortcut to run analysis.

Comment: @ekostadinov I have placed wait so the element can be loaded. But still it gives me the same error, I think it is related to the wave. Can you please help. i am not able to find any class in the inspect in the Wave.

Answer (score 1):

[Continuum](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005922626-Overview-Access-Continuum) offers an automated accessibility testing framework that uses Selenium and other technologies to test your page for accessibility concerns that can be caught without manual intervention. Like any automated solution, it won't catch everything, but it seems like it might be a good start for your use case.

You can either use the Continuum SDK directly (documentation [here](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005923506-Access-Continuum-APIs)), or start with one of the sample projects based on the technologies you're already using or are interested in using. There are free versions available for all of those at [webaccessibility.com](https://webaccessibility.com).

If a code-based solution isn't something you're interested in right now, [Continuum Explorer](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000851043-Introduction-to-Continuum-Explorer) is a Chrome browser extension that can help you catch accessibility issues as you develop your website. It can also be used to perform a quick audit of sites you've already built. A free version is available to [download on the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/continuum-explorer-commun/bafnegdlhjhdcmakjaankoogodomfbde).